# How to switch to Developer mode in Android 4.2.*

Tags: developer-options

If you get the Android 4.2.* version phone, you will notice that there is no Developer mode any more.

How can you switch to Development mode?

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings, go to phone details (where u can see kernel, Android-version, Model number etc).

Tap 7 times the Build Number (ALPS.JB2.MP.V1.3 in my case)

If you already in developer mode, the tooltip with message:
"No need, you are already a developer." will appear.